# Meaning of "upon her" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Esmeralda was a very light sleeper. She
>   woke as soon as the key turned in the lock.
>   Then, just before Frollo blew out the lantern,
>   Esmeralda saw his face. “Oh, no!” she cried
>   out faintly. “It’s the priest!”.
>   “Have pity on me!” Frollo cried out. “My
>   love for you is like a terrible fire. It’s like a
>   thousand daggers in my heart! Love me! ” He
>   held her tightly as she struggled to get away.
>   “Help! Help!” she cried, as she tried to
>   fight off the priest. But he was too strong for
>   her. With her last bit of strength, she reached
>   out for Quasimodo’s whistle and blew it as
>   hard as she could.
>   Seconds later, Frollo felt a powerful arm
>   pulling him away from Esmeralda. In the
>   darkness, Frollo could not clearly see who it
>   was—but he thought it must be Quasimodo.
>   Then he saw a gleaming sword being raised
>   over his head. “Quasimodo!” he yelled,
>   forgetting that the bell-ringer was deaf. Frollo
>   was sure that he was about to die!
>   Then, suddenly, Quasimodo hesitated.
>   “No! **No blood upon her!**” he cried out. Frollo
>   felt himself being pulled away.

Does it mean:

1: Nobody should be killed **because of her**

or

2: Nobody should be killed **in front of her eyes**

Answer (score 1):

I think OP has been misled by comments here. The cited text (shortened from ***Let there be no blood upon her***!) is effectively equivalent to ***No blood should be spilt*** (=nobody should be killed) on her account. That's to say, OP's first suggestion above is correct.

Note that in more common usages such as metaphoric ***There is blood on your hands***, the implication isn't usually ***You killed someone*** (as a deliberate act) - it's more like ***You have done/said things that led to someone being killed*** (as an unintended consequence). And any implication of possible "active / deliberate involvement" is particularly weak in the *specific* cited context.

Answer (score 1):

And yet it's the second interpretation that is right in this case: Quasimodo wants to spare Esmeralda the horror of seeing him kill Frollo. (So he drags him to another room to do it there).